# android, java rx , architecture, Concatenate Observables

Tags: java, android, architecture, rx-java

I'm learning java-rx. I am developing an application and I want to consider the following points

- The user can work offline or where the connection is very bad.
- Always display updated data to the user
- I want to prioritize the visualization of the data. With this I mean that I don't like to wait the timeout of the network and then go to consult the data to disk.

I developed the following observables in the application

```
Observable<Data> disk = ...;  
Observable<Data> network = ...;
Observable<Data> networkWithSave = network.doOnNext(data -> {  
  saveToDisk(data);
});
```

I have also declared the following subscriber

```
new Observer<List<Items>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        mView.hideProgressBar();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        mView.showLoadingError();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(List<Vault> vaults) {
                        processItems(vaults);
                    }
                }
```

I would like to receive some advice as to the correct way of concatenating these Observables.

I want the data on the disk to be displayed first. Then check the network and if there is new data then update them.

The network query might be in parallel, but If it to run before the disk does not display the disk data.

Thank you very much.
Sorry for my English

Answer (score 1):

I think `disk.concatWith(networkWithSave).subscribe(ui)` will do.

Disk data (if any) will always come first, though.

In case there is no data on disk, your disk source must complete without sending any messages. Disk source must never complete with error as this will effectively block your network source.

In your UI subscriber you may want to silently ignore `onError` (coming from network) if it has already got data from disk.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [Dan Lew Blog Post](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/06/22/loading-data-from-multiple-sources-with-rxjava/) can give you ideas.